# Plotting a data of protein diffusion trajectory

Tags: plotting

I have a set of data points of protein diffusion in x-y plane. They are sequential in time i.e, recorded at regular intervals of 20ms. Now, I need to plot a line plot in 2 dimensions, which connects them sequentially. By sequential, I mean : The (x,y) coordinates at time t=0 and t=20ms should be connected. Then t=20ms and t=40ms should be connected and so on. At any cost, the order should not go wrong. I am very new to Mathematica. Please help me do this task.

Sample data :

T    X    Y
20   1    1
40   2    2
60   2    3
80   3    3
100  3    4

Comment: Could you please provide a data sample?

Comment: Sounds like you need `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: Thank you E. Doroskevic. I will try exploring more of Mathematica and get back to you. I need to solve a bigger problem as well. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}};

ListLinePlot[data]
```

**Output:**

[image: output example]

**Reference:**

[ListLinePlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html#458040580)